# How to show $\{\{x\}\} \neq x$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $x$ be any set. Using ZFC axioms, how to show $(x,x)=\{\{x\}\} \neq x$?

Similar question: $\bigcup x \neq x?$

Solved questions: $x \neq P(x)$ ($x$ is a subset of $x$ but $x \notin x$ by the Foundation axiom)

$\{x\}=\{x,x\}\neq x$ (by the Foundation axiom)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If $x = \{ \{ x \} \}$ then $x \in \{ x \} \in \{ \{ x \} \} = x$, and so the set $\{ x , \{ x \} \}$ has no $\in$-minimal element (contradicting Foundation).

The second statement is not true.  It is clearly not true for $\varnothing$, and as Andres Caicedo has mentioned below, it is not true for plenty of nonempty sets.

Comment: $\bigcup x=x$ is satisfied by plenty of sets. For example, $x=\omega$, or $x=V_{\omega_3+\omega_1\cdot 2}$.

Comment: @Andres: Crap crap crap crap.  (And thank-you very much for pointing out what was clearly obvious to many, but not to myself.)

Answer (score 14):

It seems the following:

If $\{\{x\}\}=x$ then put $y=\{x\}$. Then $y\ni x\ni y\dots $,  that is impossible.

$\bigcup\varnothing=\varnothing$.